# Part of RelativeLayout content going off of screen because of Toolbar Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

very new to Android here! I have been working on a little project, but I have come into a minute problem. Basically, the Android Toolbar, that comes with the Basic Activity, is being calculated in to the `match-parent` height. Let me elaborate some more.

In my `activity_main.xml` I have the following piece of code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

... (fab)
```

And then in my `content_main.xml` I have the following (*snippet*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.michaeljones.testproject.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/homeBackgroundTop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now my problem is when I am setting the height of the View (programmatically) in `content_main.xml` to the height of the Parent (`RelativeLayout`) my content is going off of the screen. I have set the `RelativeLayout` to be `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, which I would expect to fill in the rest of the screen. Yet instead, it is also accounting for the Toolbar. When I remove the Toolbar this all works perfectly.

Any idea on how I could make it so the `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in the `RelativeLayout` will not account for the Android Toolbar, but instead make it the height of the screen that is not being used (all of it minus the toolbar)?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention, the following is how I am grabbing the height of the `RelativeLayout`:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus == true) {
        RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) main.findViewById(R.id.content);
        int w = content.getWidth();
        int h = content.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think wrapping what you've got in a `RelativeLayout` should fix your issue. So something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_dialpad_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/connect_main_fab_margin"
        android:background="@color/BackgroundActive"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_keypad"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hello, I have just tried what you had said, but sadly it just messed up the layout. So that I guess is not a fix :(

Comment: In what way did it mess up the layout? We are doing something very similar in our application so should be able to tweak the above to get it to display properly.

Comment: The FAB for some reason moved to the top left. Also it then acts if the Toolbar is locked to the top. The content of the `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />` goes behind the Toolbar. Not too sure on what is going on.

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on, missed the FAB part. I'll update the code above.

Comment: Also, I have this line of code at the top `<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ...`, I thought I had put that in my code above. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if that works for you.